# Align odd and even rows separately in BIRT report

Tags: birt

There is a query which brings in more than 100 records and I have mapped row number for each record. There are 2 tables designed in the BIRT layout which is mapped to the same dataset. The output of this report should be such that all the odd row numbers should appear in the LEFT and right row numbers on the RIGHT side. This works for the first few pages however after that the LEFT side remains empty and all of them come to the RIGHT side. Below is the condition used in table Filters,

LEFT Side Table

`BirtMath.mod(row["srnbr"],2) Equals 1`

RIGHT Side Table

```
BirtMath.mod(row["srnbr"],2) Equals 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the style from BIRT outline for left alignment ,
add the condition in **highlight** for data element from properties and apply the style.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jefbf.jpg)